# easygui CLOSE button (on top right of window) not functioning

Tags: python, easygui

i have created a chat system in python, using easygui for graphical user interface.
 there are minimize,maximize and close button on top right of window,but the close button is not functioning at all.i just can use the exit button which i created to close the application. i had some search and found there is a problem with easygui, so is it totally impossible to fix this problem? or how can i remove that close button from top right as there is no use for it. its final year project and i'm afraid my advisor and supervisor want try that button and i lose mark because of no function
 is there anyway to fix it or at least remove that close button?

Comment: easygui is open source, so in theory you could fix it. It's doubtful anyone here could help since you have posted any code to give some indication of what functions you're using. It's doubtful there's any way to remove the close button because it's display is controlled by the operating system.

Comment: i can post the source code, but it is around 700 lines and am not sure which part involving those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely past the due date for your assignment...sorry.  But, that was a known limitation of easygui.  An up-to-date version with a fix for that will be released soon.  If you can't wait, you can take a look at it in development form: https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui